# Can't make elements visible in Autodesk viewer when isolating fittings elements

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud7Md.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Fye.png)

When we open a 3D view and proceed to isolate some elements that are attached from each other (for example and assembly), the viewer proceeds to make a zoom extent and isolate the parts. As you can see in the clips attached, the fitting elements disappear from the viewer.

We are using the latest version (7.82) of autodesk viewer and we have found out that in previous versions (7.80) the fittings are showing properly.

We noticed that is working properly in previous versions and maybe, this is an issue corresponding to the latest version updates

Comment: I'm trying to understand the issue you addressed. Do you mean that the pipe fitting becomes invisible after isolating two pipes and one pipe fitting in v7.82 and above versions?

Comment: Haven't heard back from you, but if the issue you addressed is what I mentioned above, please try with v7.84

Comment: yes thats the problem.. I will try with that version.. thanks!